# Change variable in array with react hook setState

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having trouble to change the actif value of a certain name.
If I click on the tag 'Sport', I would like the 'actif' value in 'Sport' to change to 1 but I am not sure what is the proper way to write it, I have tried many.

```
const [activeTag, setActivetag] = useState([
        { name: "Music", value: 1, actif: 1 },
        { name: "Sport", value: 2, actif: 0 },
        { name: "VideoGames", value: 3, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Animals", value: 4, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Party", value: 5, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Arts", value: 6, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Movies", value: 7, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Travels", value: 8, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Cooking", value: 9, actif: 0 },
        { name: "Dance", value: 10, actif: 0 },
    ]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this on Click event:

```
var newArr = [... activeTag]; 
newArr[index] = your_newvalue
setActiveTag(newArr);
```

Updated, I think this one is much better:

```
 function onClick() {
   setArr(arr.map((x) => (x.name === "Sport" ? { ...x, actif: 1 } : x)));
 }
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-tree-dd7px?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: If you execute this in quickly it can loose state updates, especially if the update depends on the state before that, as in toggling a boolean value

Comment: Well, that does not reflect what I suggested, since you are not using the old state it doesnt matter. Try it for yourself, try and toggle (switch true -> false -> true -> ..) the value in state on the button click, it won't work, unless you pass a function to setArr which will use the oldState

Comment: You can check it out in my answer, I put the example up of toggling a boolean value in the state

Answer (score 0):

I created an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-morning-2n364?file=/src/App.js:620-998)

Basically you want to use the callback in setState and an onChange handler, e.g. with a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```js
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (name) => () => {
      setActivetag((oldActivetag) =>
        oldActivetag.reduce((acc, current) => {
          let tag = current;
          if (tag.name === name) {
            tag = {
              ...tag,
              actif: !tag.actif
            };
          }
          return [...acc, tag];
        }, [])
      );
    },
    []
  );
```

and use in render

```
<button onClick={onChange("Sport")}>Toggle Sport actif</button>
```

On a side note - One can argue about the usage of `useCallback`, especially since the dependency array is empty, but for the sake of mentioning it - here it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback with previous state to setter. More [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
const UserDiv = () => {
    const [activeTag, setActiveTag] = useState(yourArray);

    const handleClick = event => 
        setActiveTag(prevState =>                 
            prevState.map(el => 
                (el.name != event.target.name) ?
                {...el, actif:0} : 
                {...el, actif: 1}
            )
        )
    
    return (
        yourArray.map(el => 
            <button 
                name={el.name}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                {el.value}
            </button>
        )
    )
}
```